# Excel Graph Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: Graph]

I am trying to format my graph so that the background area changes from white to grey hashed in the area above the 100% threshold. Any ideas?

Comment: [Excel Charts With Horizontal Bands - Peltier Tech Blog](https://peltiertech.com/excel-charts-with-horizontal-bands/) shows one approach. Change the band colours to match your use case

Comment: I believe that I understand what you’re asking for, but I’m not 100% sure. Can you add an illustration of the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have your source data, the general steps are as follows：

Add two auxiliary columns, if more than 100% is fail, if less than 100% is fail

Reinsert the chart.